# How to upgrade AWS CLI to the latest version?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I recently noticed that I am running an old version of AWS CLI that is lacking some functionality I need:

```
$aws --version
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-85-generic
```

How can I upgrade to the latest version of the AWS CLI (1.10.24)?

Edit:

Running the following command fails to update AWS CLI:

```
$ pip install --upgrade awscli
Requirement already up-to-date: awscli in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Checking the version:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-85-generic
```

Comment: I had this same situation and was caused by the aws cli being originally installed via `apt-get install awscli`. Solution was to remove it first (`apt-get remove awscli`) and follow `pip install` answers below.

Comment: I did (apt-get remove awscli) but then after following (pip install...) commands I can't find the awscli executable. The output of (pip install ...) says successfully installed.

Comment: If I don't use "--user" option in pip install then I could find awscli executable under /usr/local/bin (I am on Debian Jessie). But with --user option the exec is not available in ~/.local or in any of the python installation package folders (dist-package or site-package).

Answer (score 139, accepted):

From http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html#install-with-pip

To upgrade an existing AWS CLI installation, use the --upgrade option:

```
pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Comment: I get the following message: `Requirement already up-to-date: awscli in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. Although when I run `aws --version`, I get `aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-85-generic`.

Comment: Try pip3 install --upgrade awscli

Comment: Running `sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli` and a reboot did the trick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a reboot is required after installing aws cli.

Comment: I can't believe a reboot is *required*, but in this case it was faster to reboot my vm than find an alternative [that 'reboot voodoo' is for windows].

Comment: If PyYAML failed you while installing: `pip uninstall awscli`, then `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and `pip install awscli` again.

Comment: For me helped going `sudo su` first.

Comment: you don't need to reboot, just enter to another terminal, or restart the current one

Comment: I now have aws and aws2 in my systems. How do I get rid of aws and rename my aws2 as aws?

Comment: Instead of reboot or starting another shell, you can run "hash -r" to clear the remembered utility locations.  Or "hash aws" to reset just the remembered aws executable location.

Answer (score 53):

On Linux and MacOS X, here are the three commands that correspond to each step:

```
$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Comment: updating via `pip` did not work for me - deleting `aws` and re-installing it this way did work.

Comment: You saved my day. AWS is getting poor on its documentation.

Comment: this option worked for me as I needed to upgrade `/usr/local/aws` ( not `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/aws` ) to be used by *jenkins* user

Comment: The documentation of AWS is indeed deteriorating rapidly. This is the correct answer, I can't understand why the questioner accepted an answer which they'd clearly stated in their edit didn't work - the pip packages are often behind the current latest which is a problem when using new stuff like EKS. Note: I had to exit the shell and log back in for the aws command to pick up the new version. No idea why.

Comment: If you are using `python3` run `sudo /usr/local/bin/python3.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws` instead of `sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws`

Answer (score 25):

This does not work:

> pip install --upgrade awscli

This worked fine on Ubuntu 14.04( no need to reboot also .. You would have to first install pip3 ):

> pip3 install --upgrade awscli

Comment: This may require: `apt-get install python3-pip`

Either command works equally well for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu 16.04 I used parts of the other answers and comments and just reloaded bash instead of rebooting.

I installed the aws-cli using apt so I removed that first:

```
sudo apt-get remove awscli
```

Then I could pip install (I chose to use sudo to install globally with pip2):

```
sudo pip install -U awscli
```

Since I was doing this on a server I didn't want to reboot it, but reloading bash did the trick:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

At this point I could use the new version of aws cli

```
aws --version
```

Comment: Thanks for `source ~/.bashrc` step.:)

Answer (score 12):

**Update: Upgrade instance using AWS CLI v2:**

This question and answer was initially created when there was only an AWS CLI v1.  There is now a AWS CLI v2.  The installation instructions for the AWS CLI v2 can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).

The new AWS CLI v2 has different installation instructions based on whether your EC2 instance is using Linux x86 (64-bit) or Linux ARM architecture.

For Linux x86 (64-bit) architecture execute the following commands as the root user:

```
aws --version

curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip -q awscliv2.zip
./aws/install --bin-dir /usr/local/bin --install-dir /usr/local/aws-cli --update

aws --version
```

Verify that the AWS CLI actually upgraded by looking at the output of the: `aws --version` commands.

Let's clean up after ourselves:

```
rm -rf aws
rm -f awscliv2.zip
```

For Linux ARM architecture it might work to just replace the preceding `curl` command with the following as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html):

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-aarch64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
```

---

**Original answer: Upgrade instance using AWS CLI v1 to use the most recent version of AWS CLI v1:**

If you are having trouble installing the AWS CLI using `pip` you can use the "Bundled Installer" as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-bundle.html).

The steps discussed there are as follows:

```
$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Check your AWS CLI version subsequently as a sanity-check that everything executed correctly:

```
$ aws --version
```

If the AWS CLI didn't update to the latest version as expected maybe the AWS CLI binaries are located somewhere else as the previously-given commands assume.

Determine where AWS CLI is being executed from:

```
$ which aws
```

In my case, AWS CLI was being executed from `/bin/aws`, so I had to install the
"Bundled Installer" using that location as follows:

```
$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /user/local/aws -b /bin/aws
```

Comment: using the bundled installer somehow makes the resulting docker image LARGER than using pip ... mind blowing

Comment: It may be necessary to open a new shell after installing - for some reason "aws" doesn't point to the new install until exiting and restarting.

Comment: @chad-grant Did you delete the bundled installer subsequently to using it?  I've updated my answer to just do some cleanup.

Answer (score 8):

Try
`sudo pip install --upgrade awscli`, and open a new shell.
This worked well for me (no need to reboot).

Comment: On Mac OS, I had to run `sudo pip install --upgrade awscli` for my machine to be able to uninstall the previous version of the awscli (after the initial upgrade ran successfully)

Answer (score 5):

Simple use 
`sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade`

This will upgrade all the required modules.

Comment: on my jenkins machine I didn't want to explicitly uninstall the cli, so I used this method and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 4):

On Mac you can use homebrew:

to install: `brew install awscli`

to upgrade: `brew upgrade awscli`

Make sure you don't have multiple installations: `where aws`

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

The `--upgrade` option tells pip to upgrade any requirements that are already installed. The `--user` option tells pip to install the program to a subdirectory of your user directory to avoid modifying libraries used by your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

We can follow the below commands to install AWS CLI on UBUNTU:

> sudo apt install curl
>
> curl “https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip” -o
>   “awscli-bundle.zip”
>
> unzip awscli-bundle.zip
>
> sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/ aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
>
> rm -rf awscli-bundle.zip awscli-bundle
>
> To test: aws — version

For More Info :

https://gurudathbn.wordpress.com/2018/03/31/installing-aws-cli-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

When using `sudo pip install --upgrade awscli` I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/lib'
```

By using sudo with -H option, I could fix the problem.

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, using pip will get you the [old version](https://pypi.org/project/awscli/) of awscli, `1.18.103`.

The latest version of aws-cli, `2.0.33` is on the `v2` [branch](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/v2). You can download the installer for Linux, Windows and macOS from [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/v2#installation).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install `awscli` on one of my ec2 instances where I tried both

- `sudo pip install --upgrade awscli`,
- `sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli`

which didn't worked, as I was getting errors like

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2nh71cs2/cryptography/

And rebooting servers were not an option.

Luckily, simple

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt install awscli` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I do it by removing & installing the awscli like described in this [video](https://youtu.be/sGRiRb6U4Qg?t=423)

basically:

> pip uninstall awscliv2

> pip install awscliv2

> pip install awscliv2==your-version

> pip install awscliv

(you can keep v1 along with v2 if you want)

> pip install --upgrade ...

works as well. sure.

**I do not install it globally** (like some ppl seems still do), btw. Because sometimes I need different v for different cases. so I keep it in separate python virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you can try this command

```
msiexec.exe /i https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
```

Answer (score 0):

Install or update the AWS CLI on macOS

1. curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.pkg" -o "AWSCLIV2.pkg"
2. sudo installer -pkg ./AWSCLIV2.pkg -target /

Done!
You can verify the same with below cmd

- aws --version

Answer (score 0):

**An adaptation of the answer provided by [dutoitns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58369717/1165936) to upgrade an EC2 instance to the latest AWS CLI v2: (AL2, as of 2023/11) -**

```
ec2_to_awscli2() {
  # uninstall awscli v1, and install latest v2
  aws --version;
  pip3 uninstall awscli -y;
  sudo yum remove awscli -y;
  if [[ "$(uname -m)" =~ aarch64 ]]; then arch="aarch64"; else  arch="x86_64"; fi
  curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-${arch}.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip";
  unzip awscliv2.zip;
  sudo ./aws/install;
  rm -rf aws; rm -f awscliv2.zip;
  hash aws
  aws --version
}

ec2_to_awscli2
```

This alleviates the need to know the architecture of the instance and hashes the aws alias so that the most recent cli is immediately usable.

Answer (score -1):

Try **AWS Cloud Shell**, Quick and easy

AWS CloudShell is a browser-based shell that makes it easy to securely manage, explore, and interact with your AWS resources. CloudShell is pre-authenticated with your console credentials.

Benefits

- No extra credentials to manage
- Always up to date
- No cost

More Details here https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/

- Customizable

Comment: Until unless used for a specific purpose, common day to day operations could easily be handled with Cloud shell

Answer (score -3):

To install globally, get on the sudo access
**sudo su** & then upgrade aws cli by

```
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```