# AWS CLI returning "unknown option" on run-instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Executing query:

`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-7a85a01a --security-group-ids sg-756ae512 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --tag-specifications ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}] --subnet-id subnet-cc0b0e8a`

Its throwing an error saying:

`Unknown options: --tag-specifications, ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]`

Does anybody know if this is depricated, or is the syntax different from expected?  I've been running in circles with this.

Possible solution with new syntax:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxxxx  --security-group-ids sg-ef95c791 --count 1 --instance-type m4.2xlarge --key-name mypemkey --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PublicIpAddress,InstanceId]
```

The best I can come up with, seems to be working:

`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-7a85a01a --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name mykeypair --subnet-id sn-756ae512 --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=production}]' --associate-public-ip-address --output=text`

Comment: Your edit only shows that you removed the `--tag-specification` option, WTF?

Comment: Correct answer is below.  Needed to upgrade.Mostly the docs told me I cant add tags during instance creation.  I posted the last command I got working, which will return the instance-id, which could be passed to the next command - to tag the instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this issue today and figured it out after an hour or so of struggling through the infamously horrendous AWS documentation.

The problem was that the installation instructions (`pip install` and using the bundled installer) are just wrong: though the commands were copied perfectly and the requirements (specifically the "Python 2 version 2.6.5+ or Python 3 version 3.3+") were met, the `aws-cli` package would never install/update past `1.11.13`.

The solution: [use `pip3 install` instead of `pip install`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969391/how-to-upgrade-aws-cli-to-the-latest-version). This updated it to `1.11.97`, which enabled the `--tag-specifications` parameter. I don't know if this will solve the problem for you, but I suspect many Ubuntu users will experience this, so I decided to post it anyway.

Comment: My system is running pip 9.0.1 and Python 2.7, and I did not have this problem. So, I have offered my own answer.

Comment: The lack of consistency in aws products is baffling, so having many different possible solutions is always welcome. Bezos works in mysterious ways.

Comment: I don't think it's baffling. The whole idea is that independent teams wrote their own entry points. It's natural that a coding style didn't coalesce until much of the work was done.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is correct, per the documentation; but your AWS client is too old to support the `--tag-specifications` option.

[On OS X, at least] use `pip install --upgrade --user awscli` to upgrade the client to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

found an answer. Different syntax in the call:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

edit:

```
QUERY=$(aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ${AMI_ID} --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name ${KEY_PAIR} --subnet-id ${SUBNET_ID} \
 --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value='${EC2_TAG}'}]' --associate-public-ip-address --output=text )
```

Comment: Can you include your completed, correct code sample for future readers?  Simply linking to the documentation with no comment as to what change you actually made isn't a sufficient answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Shared my workaround, not using the 'name' tag.  I'm using CONemu emulator - so pip is not installed.  I think Jonathan Voss' solution was probably the right answer.  AWS CLI syntax can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as a possible solution. My issue was similar in terms of the error output, though I was dealing with the 'aws cloudfront update-continuous-deployment-config' command. Turns out the json I was passing to it was **not** in a compact form. I had to run it through jq to make it compact, and then everything was fine.

BEFORE CODE:
`CF_CD_CONFIG=$(cat cf_cd_config.json)`

AFTER CODE:
`CF_CD_CONFIG=$(cat cf_cd_config.json | jq -c)`

`aws cloudfront update-continuous-deployment-policy --continuous-deployment-policy-config ${CF_CD_CONFIG} --id ${CF_CD__ID} --if-match ${CF_CD_ETAG}`

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a single quote for `'` --tag-specifications value:

eg. from [aws ec2 run-instances documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html):

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=webserver,Value=production}]' 'ResourceType=volume,Tags=[{Key=cost-center,Value=cc123}]'
```

Comment: Tried that fix, still same output.

Comment: The single quote is only required (in particular cases) by your shell, not AWS.