# How do I get Lightsail options on AWSCLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, snapshot, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to add automatic snapshot functionality to my lightsail instance.  I have installed and updated the awscli through pip.

Everything checks out fine, but there is no option available for lightsail in the cli.  I followed this tutorial [from joe0](https://www.joe0.com/2017/07/29/how-to-schedule-nightly-backups-of-amazon-lightsail-instance-by-leveraging-aws-command-line-interface-cli/)

After executing the command to get instance snapshots, I get this:
[Awscli image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVzb.png)

Note: No lightsail option exists.

Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks for your time!

Comment: What version of AWS CLI do you have? `aws --version`

Comment: AWSCLI version 1.11.13

Answer (score 1):

You need a newer version of the AWS CLI. Version `1.11.13` does not include `lightsail`. It appears it was added in [`1.11.23`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst). The latest version in `pip` is `1.15.29`. Try running `pip install awscli --upgrade` again and make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: Did it twice.  It is stuck at the same version.  Any idea how to force the update?  Thanks!

Comment: Try some of the other suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969391/how-to-upgrade-aws-cli-to-the-latest-version

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled awscli.  That did the trick!  Thanks, Brandon!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I uninstalled and reinstalled awscli.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Brandon Miller.