# How does one update AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Googling sends me to this page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html

But that page has no instructions for updating.

Running

```
aws --version
```

I see that I am out of date. Is the process to just uninstall/reinstall?

Comment: Yes, just uninstall and then reinstall. It says it there in the red **Important** box right at the top of the page.

Comment: You can use brew on Mac or Chocolatey on Windows to update installed software (that was originally installed using those tools).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade AWS CLI to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969391/how-to-upgrade-aws-cli-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: What Operating System are you using?

Comment: I would use `pip` to update it as mentioned by @Ervin Szilagyi. You can install a specific version if you like(e.g `pip install awscli==1.18.105`). In case of issue in updating, you can also try `pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade`.

Comment: I am on Windows. The red "important" box is about upgrading from version 1. I already have version 2.  I assume there is an upgrade mechanism.